# drag and drop with accurate drop position

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) drag and drop API but i want it to drop on the specific position the cursor left of, instead it is always going to the top right. I have tried this code but i dont know if i am doing it right

```
var dragObj, count=0;

function set_drag_drop(obj)
{
    if(count>0){
        obj.adx = 10; 
        obj.ady = 10 + (count*100)
    }else{
        obj.adx = 0;
        obj.ady = 0;
    }
    count++;
    
    obj.onmousedown = function(e)
    {
        var rect = obj.getBoundingClientRect();
        obj.dx = rect.left - e.clientX;
        obj.dy = rect.top - e.clientY;
        obj.isDown = true;
        dragObj = this;
    }

    obj.onmouseup = function(e)
    {
        obj.isDown = false;
    }

    document.onmousemove = function(e)
    {
        if(dragObj && dragObj.isDown)
        {
            dragObj.style.left = e.pageX -dragObj.adx+ dragObj.dx +"px";
            dragObj.style.top = e.pageY -dragObj.ady+ dragObj.dy + "px";
        }
    }
}

set_drag_drop(document.getElementById("obj1"));
```

[check it out here](https://codepen.io/KhAzZaKa/pen/MWKOVRx)

Comment: `check it out here` link doesn't work

Comment: i updated the full code link